# CodeIgniter form validation using session variables

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

How do I get the CodeIgniter form validation to validate the `$_SESSION` if there is no passed form data? I tried manually setting the `$_REQUEST` variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

i.e. I have a function `search` in the controller which validates the form input passed, and either returns you to the previous page with errors, or else moves you onto the next page. But I want this function to also work if you previously filled out this page, and the info is stored in the `$_SESSION` variable.

```
function search () {
    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("flightID", "Flight Time", "required|callback_validFlightID");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("time", "Flight Time", "required|callback_validFlightTime");

    $this->setRequest(array("flightID", "time"));

    // adding session check allows for inter-view navigation
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

        // some application logic here

        $this->load->view("seats", $data);
    } else {
        $this->logger->log($_REQUEST, "request");
        // redirect back to index
        $this->index();
    }   
}
function setRequest () {
    // make sure none of the parameters are set in the request
    foreach ($vars as $k) {
        if (isset($_REQUEST[$k])) {
            return;
        }   
    }   

    foreach ($vars as $k) {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$k])) {
            $_REQUEST[$k] = $_SESSION[$k];
        }   
    }   

}
```

Comment: You should include code.

Comment: You use native php sessions? I'm answer, because CI on default use own session based on cookie, and it not store variables in $_SESSION

Comment: @joni_jones The $_SESSION variable does in fact contain the data I think it does (I did a FirePHP logging of the $_SESSION and $_REQUEST variables)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the form post info in a session using the following codeigniter functions

```
$formdata = array(
                    'flightID' => $this->input->post('flightID'),
                    'time' => $this->input->post('time')
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($formdata);
```

and the information can be retrieved with the following

```
$this->session->userdata('flightID')
$this->session->userdata('time')
```

Answer (score 0):

`form_validation` works directly with `$_POST`, so use that instead of `$_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is setting Post values manually which is not natively 
supported by CodeIgniter. So what we're doing first is extending the core.
Create a new file (MY_Input.php) and paste the following contents into it:

```
class MY_Input extends CI_Input{

    function set_post($key, $value)
    {
        $_POST[$key] = $value;
    }

}
```

That's a very basic implementation of your purpose but it's enough to test around. You might want to extend it to make it fit your needs (f.e. allowing the input of arrays).

So now. In your controller you can check if something has been posted by a user. If not you'll be just setting the post variable manually with your new method of the Input class.

```
class Some_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function index()
    {
        // The user hasn't filled out a field?
        if(!$this->input->post('a_key'))
        {
            // Let's set the postfield to the value of a session key
            $this->input->set_post('a_key', $this->session->userdata('mystoredkey'));
        }
    }

}
```

After having set your postfield manually, it can be handled by the form validation library as it is meant to be.

That should be your way to go :)
You can really do some pretty things if you're not afraid of hacking the core. Many people are, don't be one of them!

Happy coding